# My Git Pull/Push records from different account

Tags: git, git-bash, git-push, git-pull, git-config

How to change the account in git during pulling/pushing?

I am using git bash in my terminal whenever I pull/push. After that it shows on our repo's activity that I **PUSHED** as different person.

Here's an Example: **'name-of-other-account-here' pushed to branch master**

Which is supposed to be:**'my-account-here' pushed to branch master**

Comment: use git config to change configuration

Comment: git config user.email <email address>. git config user.name <username> to config your local repo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your `user/email` in `git config`.

```
# Change just for a single repo. Go into the repo.
$ git config --local user.name <your-name>
$ git config --local user.email <your-email>

# Or, change globally (for all repos)
$ git config --global user.name <your-name>
$ git config --global user.email <your-email>

$ git config --list       # check 'user.name' and 'user.email'
```